# Li-Ion battery questions

Tags: batteries

**After putting battery in freezer overnight** (in ziplock bag to avoid moisture (according to sites battery loses >20% Capacity in >3 months to a year) **Does the rapid heating up cause by turning phone on and games harm battery *after* storing it in a cold place like a freezer?**

**Exactly how much is it safe to discharge?** (I've found to avoid full discharge on several sites but no site says exactly how much of a discharge isn't harmful except about 20% but with no sources to back it up and I don't know how accurate is that "about".)

[please see at least this comment on bottom of this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102702/li-ion-battery-questions#comment202449_102709)

Comment: This appears to be two separate questions, perhaps split them up.  Also it would help if you could link the sites that you have seen these claims on.

Comment: A quick google search reveals these sites and I'd link them but Im not sure which site you d like most

Comment: @David what do you mean by split them up?

Comment: The question would be most useful with links to anything you plan on using as source material.

Comment: I think these questions are OK together. Panasonic say this: http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ACI4000/ACI4000PE5.pdf

Comment: @David please read again.Im asking not about operating cold batteries but will battery be harmed from rapid heating up such as gaming)

Comment: @Andyaka Ive just read through all 37 pages of the document and although Ive learnt new things I couldnt find answers to the questions

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be worried about structural effects of expansion and contraction of the crystal structure of the electrolyte. If that's your concern, you really shouldn't be, especially while the device is off. It is true that intensely low temps could mess things up, and so could intensely high ones. But the temperatures involved in the transition from a typical freezer to high in the operating range of the common lithium battery pack aren't sufficient to cause loss of capacity or structural damage by themselves. Big bloated battery packs happen because of outgassing and extreme internal temperatures near end of life or with abnormal use.

It is true that lithium ion capacity suffers if maintained at full charge or no charge for a long period of time. It seems to do bad things to the crystal structure, and that is still getting researched. I know for fact the newer iPads have oversized battery packs crammed into them, but I don't know how much. I suspect they say 99% on their battery readout when they are at about 90 or 95% of the equilibrium point for the given voltage; that is, they just aren't actually full, so they won't suffer the full charge degradation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your information is accurate. What I have read from many different sources is that lithium ion rechargeable batteries loose capacity when stored at a full charge at HIGHER temperatures, not lower.  They loose 20%/year when stored fully charged at 25 degrees celcius.

Look here: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/elevating_self_discharge

If you mean that you are storing your battery in the freezer to avoid the 20% loss in capacity over the year then that makes sense.  Just by using you phone, the battery should not get hot enough that it should harm the battery (I don't remember where I read that).

However, you might be better to store it in the fridge as you don't need to keep it freezer cold to prevent the capacity loss, just look at the numbers in the link I provided above.  Storing at 0 degrees celcius is cold enough, and most fridges are at 4 degrees celcius, which is likely close enough.  This way you are not exposing your battery to the extremes of temperate and risking damage.

As far as the second question, are you asking what is the best state of discharge for li-ion for storage?  The answer is a 40% charge is the best state of charge to store the li-ion rehargeable.

Comment: `As far as the second question, are you asking what is the best state of discharge for li-ion for storage? The answer is a 40% charge is the best state of charge to store the li-ion rehargeable.` I read that too but I have two batteries and I want to know exactly what % I should switch to other battery since Ive read that deep discharges are bad and I also read that 40% charge is best for storage but Im not really sure if that is because of the "avoid deep discharges" or different reasons.

Comment: Also the capacity loss written on sites is different thats why I wrote >3 months=http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries to a year=wikipedia.

Comment: Perhaps the values given are for different li ion battery types.

Comment: @user42276 The age related loss in capacity is due in part to the negative electrode degrading.  At fuller charges, it will be full of lithium ions which can speed up the degredation. (I can't find the reference where I read this, I am just repeating what I remember so it may not be 100% accurate and don't take it as law, but it is due to something like that).  The 40% charge allow for some charge to remain to power the protection circuit and avoid the deep discharge that also reduces the li-ion battery life, but keeps most of the lithium of of the negative electrode.

Comment: Check out this table: It show the number of charge/discharge cycles you will get from a lithium ion battery for a given level of depth of discharge that you choose to use: (which I think is what you are asking in question 2)   http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: I've actually seen this during my research but I'm still asking because Im not sure how exactly the values for different things I found correlate with each other. For example: exactly what discharge% allows the most discharge cycles and how this % correlates to the values given for best storing temp and all this to the capacity at a given cycle.(that's still not all correlations)Also Im not sure how many possible Correlations to take into account

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't discharge a lithium ion battery to below about 2.9 volts. If you take it below 2.7 V you may never get it to recover.

According to Panasonic you should operate batteries/cells between -10C and +60C and from [NASA](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20070032054.pdf) here are some results for testing a Panasonic battery and measuring temperature rises during charge and discharge: -

[image]

I would assume that the rate at which the temperature rises under heavy ish discharge conditions won't be related to starting temperature very much.

Comment: This is a very good find showing that the temperature rises while discharging and drops below starting temp (same as rest temp if Im correct) for a while before going back to rest temp (If I understand this correctly).`However this doesnt show the above correlations referencing to different temps so why would you assume?`

Comment: I would assume that the same temperature change will happen at lower temperatures because the temperature effects are due to energy in and energy out variations and why would these alter (given the same charge and discharge energy rates) at a different temperature other than possibly condensing humidity might reduce the change due to conduction away from the cell. If you put so many watts into an object it rises a certain temperature and by and large this isn't greatly affected by ambient temperature levels across a wide range.

Comment: I know that lower temp usually means lower resistance and resistance cause heating up but I think I might be missing something.So is it possible that rapid heating up from the freezer temp to battery working temp wil harm it?

Comment: I think the point that Andyaka is making is that the temp rise will be a certain amount that is independent of the starting temperature. Therefore using the phone straight out of the freezer should not harm the battery.  Your point about resistance and heat is correct, but you might be looking at it a little backwards - a hotter battery doesn't cause a higher resistance, a battery with higher resistance will result in a higher temperature when charged or discharged at higher rates.  So starting temperature should not make a noticeable change in resistance even straight out of the freezer.